# Como acceder a un elemento dentro de una estructura?

Tags: c, datos

Tengo la siguiente estructura

```
typedef struct
{
    char* c_data_0;
    int* i_data_0;
} STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA;

STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA* struct_almacen_data = NULL;
```

aqui le reserve espacio en memoria para tres estructuras

```
struct_almacen_data = (STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA *) malloc (3 * sizeof (STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA));
```

No se preocupen por la liberacion y la nullidad de la variable ya lo hice

ahora quiero asignarle espacio para cada uno de los miembros

```
xxx.xxxxx =  (char *) malloc (12 * sizeof (char));
```

lo que he intentado y no me ha funcionado:

- Accederlo como si fueran arreglo, matrices y no me arroja resultados satisfactorios todo en tiempo de compilacion

  *(struct_almacen_data[0]+0).c_data_0
  error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA' and 'int')

  Quiero acceder a la estructura cero y luego al campo cero y el campo uno

luego

```
Quiero acceder a la estructura uno y luego al campo cero y el campo uno
```

luego

```
Quiero acceder a la estructura dos y luego al campo cero y el campo uno
```

y de esta forma he pensado pero no encuentro la forma de expresarlo en codigo.

```
|)
```

Lo mas cercano que encontre es:

```
(*struct_almacen_data).c_data_0
```

pero aqui no se a donde esta apuntando en la estructura y si quiero la siguiente estructura como le aumento

Gracias por leerme y colaborarme.

Ejemplo demostrable para @Trauma

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* c_data_0;
    int* i_data_0;
} STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA;

STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA struct_general_data;

void
print_record (STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA*);

int
main (int argc,
      char* argv[])
{
    struct_general_data.i_data_0 = (int *) malloc (3 * sizeof (int));

    print_record (&struct_general_data);

    free (struct_general_data.i_data_0);
    struct_general_data.i_data_0 = NULL;

    return 0;
}

void
print_record (STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA* _struct_general_data)
{
    printf ("[0]%i\n"
            "[1]%i\n"
            "[2]%i\n",
            _struct_general_data->i_data_0,
            _struct_general_data->i_data_0+1,
            _struct_general_data->i_data_0+2);
}
```

Comment: Has probado algo como `struct_almacen_data[0]->c_data_0` para intentar registrar ahí memoria para el puntero de Char? Es decir, con el operador flecha?

Comment: Me sale el error:
error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA')

Comment: A mi lo que me interesa aqui es que malloc este tomando 2 argumentos. Eso no entiendo como compila, hace rato que no uso C, pero recuerdo que solo tomaba el tamaño en bytes. Alguien me ilumina?

Comment: @Pablochaches como dices, malloc recibe un solo argumento. Probablemente el OP se haya equivocado y se refería a calloc

Comment: @braver Buena onda pa

Comment: @Pablochaches; tienes razon al transcribir el ejemplo cambie por COMA el ASTERISCO. Favor disculpame

Comment: Para mi no, **para todos**. Uno de los motivos de cierre dice, literalmente: `
Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.` Y en el estado anterior, tu pregunta cumplía con dicho motivo de cierre.

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de que en el `malloc()` deberías haber puesto `3*sizeof(int)` (en vez de 2), pues en realidad son tres elementos a los que luego intentas acceder, entiendo que tu duda está en la sintaxis necesaria para acceder a cada uno de esos tres elementos.

Sería tan simple como lo siguiente:

```
void
print_record (STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA* _struct_general_data)
{
    printf ("[0]%i\n"
            "[1]%i\n"
            "[2]%i\n",
            _struct_general_data->i_data_0[0],
            _struct_general_data->i_data_0[1],
            _struct_general_data->i_data_0[2]);
}
```

¡Sí! Estoy usando una sintaxis de arrays a pesar de que `i_data_0` no es un array sino un puntero a int. Esto funciona porque cada vez que el compilador encuentra la sintaxis `a[x]` lo que compila es en realidad `*(a+x)`, que hace uso de aritmética de punteros. Por eso hay tanta confusión entre arrays y punteros en C, porque en realidad el compilador trata ambos de la misma forma cuando los encuentra en expresiones.

Si prefieres usar la sintaxis de puntero, sería así:

```
void
print_record (STRUCT_GENERAL_DATA* _struct_general_data)
{
    printf ("[0]%i\n"
            "[1]%i\n"
            "[2]%i\n",
            *_struct_general_data->i_data_0,
            *(_struct_general_data->i_data_0+1),
            *(_struct_general_data->i_data_0+2));
}
```